# $routeParams in a controller for index.html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an application that only uses an index with a controller main.js. I want the content to be defined by the URL, so I want to use $routeParams in the controller. My problem is that it turns up empty.

This is in my app.js

```
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/:guid', {
            templateUrl: '/index.html',
            controller: 'MyCollectionUnitCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });   
});
```

The controller:

```
    .controller('MyCollectionUnitCtrl',
    function ($scope, $location, $routeParams) {
        console.log($routeParams.guid); // Undefined
}
```

I've doubled checked that the module-names are the same.

The problem is that none of the code from the controller runs. I tested this by adding a console.log at the top. Index is not even a template, as I use no partials. **I can't find anything about routing when only using one view, so here's where I'm stuck.**

It doesn't work when I just define the controller with ng-controller neither.

Ideas? Something I'm missing? Is this a stupid question that's easily explained by documentation? I appreciate all comment, answers and feedback you can give me.

Thank you!

**EDIT:**
I've also tried to define ng-controller in the index.html, and then only have controller in the routingConfig, but that did not work either.

**EDIT2**: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gFz6h9mqYX1KLw7kP6nu?p=info)

Comment: Could you add all of your code as the route stuff looks fine.

Comment: Do you have a ng-view element in your index? Edit: Oh, you don't use partials. In that case using ng-view would be wrong anyway.

Comment: Could you do a plunker - might be easier to figure out what is wrong

Comment: I think the best way to go is to directly attach the controller to your view in the view code via ng-controller attribute. Then you can access the route parameters by injecting and accessing $routeParams.

Comment: Thanks for the response, guys! @kasoban This might seem stupid, but what do you mean by 'injecting and accessing $routeParams'? Not following you there. Tried defining it directly in ng-controller, with the routeConfig shown as above, but that did not work. I think it's the config that's the problem as there is no template for a partial view, just an index.html and a controller. Thanks again!

Comment: @Esso you're trying to use $routeProvider for something it isn't really designed for. See for reference: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Oct/15/Routing-to-a-Controller-with-no-View-in-Angular

It really doesn't work when you have a DIV in your index.html with attribute ng-controller="MyCollectionUnitCtrl" ?

Comment: @kasoban No, it doens't when I use ng-controller, no. It's weird. Seems the route just doesn't work when there isn't partials.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to find out actual problem with your code snippet, but i think you are missing ngRoute module.

Add angular-route.js script in your html and add ngRoute dependency in your module.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the tip, but it's already added. I can make a Plunker as mentioned earlier